# How to add individual citations or copyrights to an eBook?

Tags: creative-writing, copyright, citations, ebook

I'm compiling my first book. In this book, I have translated several legends, fairytales, and stories of my country (El Salvador).

Most of them are loosely based on different books, blogs, newspapers, etc. I have all book names, Authors, Storytellers, and Blogs in my notes; however, I don't know what is the best way to add them to the credits.

- Should they be added at the end of each story?
- Should they be added as a bibliography?
- Or in a section at the beginning of the book?

Personally, in the past, I have written only scientific papers and technical documentation and for each section, I have used the IEEE format.

[image: references]

Nevertheless, I don't think this one will work in my case since I'm not citing anything specific, but the full legend can be based on two sources, for instance:

1. http://leyendasdeelsalvador.com/el-griton-de-media-noche
2. [https://creepypasta.fandom.com/es/wiki/El_Gritón](https://creepypasta.fandom.com/es/wiki/El_Grit%C3%B3n)

Technically, all stories are mostly my own interpretations since there are no direct translations from Spanish to English of any of them, but I'd like to respect the legacy of all these fantastic storytellers.

Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Federico.  Thanks for a great first question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a paragraph for each story under the story title, then separated from the story by a line or something like that.  Like how many cookbooks do it.  Sometimes they explain about the recipe, how they discovered it, how their family used it, etc, before giving the actual recipe.

Include the source(s) for the story and any other notes you wish to add.

Comment: Especially for an ebook, where people are more likely to read linearly and less likely to look for a note in the bibliography at the end.  (Or at least that's what I've observed -- if you have a physical book you're more likely to even notice that there *is* a bibliography at the end before you start reading, and it's way easier to hold your place as you jump back and forth.)